# Having a hard time ensuring each of my ".nav-link" elements have an href attribute attached to it

Tags: html, navigation

Each of my nav links work in my code, and I cannot find the solution as to why it will not pass the test when I run my code through freecodecamp. Here is the code in question:

```
<div class="navigation">
     <nav id="navbar">
       <header class="dragonball">Dragon Ball</header>
       <a class="nav-link" href="#creator">
         Creator
         </a>
       <a class="nav-link" href="#characters">
         Characters
         </a>
       <a class="nav-link" href="#sagas">
         Sagas
         </a>
       <a class="nav-link" href="#transformations">
         Transformations
       </a>
       <a class="nav-link" href="#overview">
         Overview
       </a>
     </nav>
     </div>
```

Is there something missing somewhere? As far as functionality, clicking on these elements works as intended, directing you to the portion of the page it displays. Please help!

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about the [best way to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to provide a **minimal**, **reproducible** example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Sharing your HTML and CSS code as a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) will also make it a lot easier for the community to help you.

Comment: What might help you, at first sight: you need to attribute an ID to an element, then link to this ID using #elementName just like you did. In other words, the links are OK, but you now need to attribute this ID to an element somewhere on the page, setting `id="creator"` to the element, for example.

Comment: I figured it out, turns out my ID for the "Sagas" section was the problem. The ID and the href target did not match, the ID assigned had a capital "S" lol. Thanks for replying.